# Retrieve data using date in rails using ajax

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I am basic to rails, JavaScript and Ajax. I have rails query to retrieve data from three table using JOINS. I want to retrieve data by selecting the date option and I want to implement with Ajax or JavaScript.

Following is the rails Query

```
@query = ItemType.select("name, item_id, sum(quantity) as Total_Quantity_Itemwise, sum(price_value) as Item_Total_Amount, price_value, order_items.created_at Date").joins('INNER JOIN items ON items.item_type = item_types.id', 'INNER JOIN order_items ON order_items.item_id = items.id').group("item_id").order(" order_items.created_at")
```

[image: Click to view the result of the query]

and also help me getting total amount at bottom as shown in the next image

```
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>Item Name</th>
    <th>Quantity</th>
    <th>Amount</th>
  </tr>
  <% @new_query.each do |results| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= results.name %></td>
      <td><%= results.Total_Quantity_Itemwise %></td>
      <td><%= results.Item_Total_Amount %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
  <tr>
    <th>Total of all rows</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><% @new_query.sum(:price_value) %></td>
  </tr>
</table>`
```

[image: Click here to view how total to be displayed at bottom]

Answer (score 0):

Initially the page will be loaded with no content using the html.erb template and you will have an empty div with some id as reference for div.

When the user select a date and click on a button, you can add a script to listen to the click event and make an ajax call like shown below

```
$("#button").click(function() {
  $.ajax({
      url: "/calculate_price",
      type: "GET",
      dataType: 'script',
      data: {date: (#date_field_selector).val()}
  });
});
```

And you can get the date string and you can access that value and make necessary conversions and use it in query and it will render js.erb where you can place the content inside the div that we had kept in html.

Before doing this, we need to create a partial file and the html part has to be within that file and you can send the locals to the partial and use it instead of the variable `@new_query`

To display the sum at the bottom, you can just create an array variable and keep pushing the price of each entry as you know the total price of each item and you can sum the array and display it.